# FCKeditor on MediaWiki with PHP 5.3.2 installed

Tags: mediawiki, fckeditor

Trying to install *FCKEditor* extension for MediaWiki. Following instruction on official site - getting copy from svn.

After that - include it into ***LocalSettings.php*** with:

**require_once("$IP/extensions/FCKeditor/FCKeditor.php");**

Than i got error when try to open my Wiki:

```
Magic word 'NORICHEDITOR' not found

Backtrace:
#0 /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php(244):     Language->getMagic(Object(MagicWord))
#1 /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php(197): MagicWord->load('NORICHEDITOR')
#2 /var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/FCKeditor/FCKeditor.body.php(79):     MagicWord::get('NORICHEDITOR')
#3 [internal function]: FCKeditor_MediaWiki::onParserBeforeInternalParse(Object(Parser), '<div class='noa...', Object(StripState))
#4 /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/Hooks.php(117): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(870): wfRunHooks('ParserBeforeInt...', Array)
#6 /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(327): Parser->internalParse('<div class='noa...')
#7 /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/Article.php(3557): Parser->parse('<div class='noa...', Object(Title), Object(ParserOptions), true, true, 0)
#8 /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/Article.php(989): Article->outputWikiText('<div class='noa...', false)
#9 /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/Wiki.php(450): Article->view()
#10 /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/Wiki.php(63): MediaWiki->performAction(Object(OutputPage), Object(Article), Object(Title), Object(User), Object(WebRequest))
#11 /usr/share/mediawiki/index.php(116): MediaWiki->initialize(Object(Title), Object(Article), Object(OutputPage), Object(User), Object(WebRequest))
#12 {main}
```

I have installed MediaWiki 1.15.1, PHP 5.3.2.

I found some information about problems with this PHP version, but no solutions can be found.

Extension: [www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:FCKeditor_(Official)](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk%3aFCKeditor_%28Official%29)

Comment: P.S. apt-get install mediawiki gives only version 1.15. For PHP 5.3.2 need MW version 1.17+ and i got it from official site than install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got an extension version not compatible with your MediaWiki version. Pick a correct version [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special%3aExtensionDistributor/FCKeditor). Also, you should know that your MW is outdated and does not receive critical security updates and that FCKeditor has been abandoned by its developers.

Comment: Thanks, for the link. Updated to MediaWiki version 1.19 and download FCKeditor trunk version from this link. Not MW works fine.